# Mongodb find query behaviour understanding using explain

Tags: mongodb

I am on MongoDB shell version: 3.0.15

I have been analyzing a query and I didn't understand the specific behavior

For: testcollection has two keys, "state" and "all"

```
db.testcollection.find( {"state" : 1}).explain(true)
```

the `keysexamined` and `nreturned` are correct: 2568 docs

but for

```
db.testcollection.find( {"state" : 1}).limit(1000).explain(true)
```

the `nreturned` becomes `101` and `keysexamined` `102`

Without index, a `collscan` is hit and returns `101` docs in `nreturned`. If proper index is added it hits for this query and ixscan is done with `nreturned` still `101`

From my understanding and also from https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/cursors/index.html, I wouldn't have been surprised if without limit it returned me the default doc count of `101`, but here, with limit explain shows `nreturned` `101` doc after restriction instead of `2568` docs, and when no `limit` is provided, `nreturned` has `101` docs in the explain query.

Why does limit lead into showing `nreturned`101 in explain query?

Comment: Can you post explain plan for both of these queries:  db.testcollection.find( {"state" : 1}).explain("executionStats") and db.testcollection.find( {"state" : 1}).limit(1000).explain("executionStats") ?

Comment: @Astro

https://pastebin.com/99VpEZ2r - db.testcollection.find( {"state" : 1}).explain("executionStats")

and https://pastebin.com/3EJZvu0m for db.testcollection.find( {"state" : 1}).limit(1000).explain("executionStats")

Comment: Also, from https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-24727 I understand that limit would return only a single batch, but the ticket also mentions that it should return more than 101 docs in the first batch if n>101 if limit is provided for mongo versions less than 3.2 and I am on 3.0. Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: db.testcollection.find( {"state" : 1}).explain("executionStats") - returns 1000 docs? and db.testcollection.find( {"state" : 1}).limit(1000).explain("executionStats") returns 101 docs?  please confirm

Comment: Since this is on mongo shell, it runs me the buffered response. I noticed this behavior of explain while running explain query on another one of the queries I was working to analyze the index and performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you described aligned with the issue [SERVER-24547](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-24547), where it was stated that:

> Explain("allPlansExecution") does not honour limit() if batchSize() is not specified

This issue affects MongoDB version 3.0.12 and later (in the 3.0 series), and this was fixed in newer versions of MongoDB (i.e. 3.2 and newer) as per [SERVER-17577](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17577).

Please note that as of this writing, 3.0.15 is quite old and is not supported anymore. If this is a new deployment, it's best to start with a more recent version of MongoDB (currently 4.0.3) so you don't get bitten by an old bug that was fixed in later versions.

Comment: Planning to upgrade mongo soon. This was helpful, I was wondering if my understanding of the query was incorrect.
I was wondering how the query returned proper data limit but the query execution showed different information. This explains that it was an issue with explain query itself. I will try out on latest mongo. Thanks!